# mysql query optimizaiton

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

could you please optimize the below mysql query.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.cust_id ) as total FROM all_ids AS a LEFT JOIN id_details AS b ON a.cust_id = b.cust_id, users p WHERE (a.status = 'A' or a.status = 'I') and b.cust_id IS NOT NULL and a.type = 'abc' AND a.user_id = p.id AND p.team = 'customers';
```

Comment: Erm, what is your question? What do you want to optimize?

Comment: This is Stack Overflow, not your Query Optimizer site.

Comment: This might be better over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You may want to add GROUP BY a.useri_id
2. Replace (a.status = 'A' or a.status = 'I') with a.status IN ('A', 'I')
3. As for speeding it up, you need to add indexes to the following columns: a.status, a.type, p.team
4. Also consider changing the following columns from strings to integers and maybe use an external lookup table: a.status, a.type, p.team